# Loading multiple csv files of a folder into one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, glob

i have multiple csv files saved in one folder with the same column layout and want to load it into python as a dataframe in pandas.

The question is really simliar to this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330524/speed-up-the-process-of-import-multiple-csv-into-python-dataframe)

I am using the following code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
salesdata = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("TransactionData\Promorelevant\*.csv"):
    appenddata = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=";")
    salesdata = salesdata.append(appenddata,ignore_index=True)
```

Is there a better solution for it with another package?

This is taking to much time.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest use list comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob("TransactionData\Promorelevant*.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=";") for f in files]

salesdata = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv` can load data using file path, any specific reason for using `glob`?

Comment: @Shiva - Yes, `glob` return all filepaths, so it is necessary.

Comment: This is barely any different from the question? Though I guess `concat` can be faster than `append` (or does append use concat behind the scenes?). It could be better optimized as it is one operation I guess.

Answer (score 6):

With a help from [link to actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

This seems to be the best one liner:

```
import glob, os    
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "*.csv"))))
```

Comment: could you specify your solotion?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using bash will be faster:

```
head -n 1 "TransactionData/Promorelevant/0.csv" > merged.csv
tail -q -n +2 TransactionData/Promorelevant*.csv >> merged.csv
```

Or if using from within a jupyter notebook

```
!head -n 1 "TransactionData/Promorelevant/0.csv" > merged.csv
!tail -q -n +2 "TransactionData/Promorelevant*.csv" >> merged.csv
```

The idea being that you won't need to parse anything.

The first command copies the header of one of the files. 
You can skip this line if you don't have a header. 
Tail skips the headers for all the files and adds them to the csv.

Appending in Python is probably more expensive.

Of course, make sure your parse is still valid using pandas.

```
pd.read_csv("merged.csv")
```

Curious to your benchmark.

Comment: @PV8 What do you not understand? First line copies the header of one of the files to `merged.csv`, the second line appends all csvs but omitting their headers. Since it does not have to parse anything it will be lightning fast.

Comment: assuming my files in the folder are named: `0.csv`, `1.csv`and so on, and the folder path is still: `TransactionData\Promorelevant`, what do I have to write to use your code?

Comment: @PV8 Updated the example with the folder, does it work?

Comment: the 1 is identified as invalid syntax, I hav eto run this in jupyter notebook right?

Comment: @PV8 Updated to add quotes, the better slashes, and you have to have the `!` in front if using jupyter. The server the notebook is running on is linux based right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202381/discussion-between-pv8-and-pascalvkooten).

Answer (score 0):

i checked all this approaches  except the bash one with the time function (only one run, and also note that the files are on a shared drive).

Here are the results:

My approach: 1220.49

List comphrension+concat: 1135.53

concat+map+join:  1116.31

I will go for list comphrension+concat which will save me some minutes and i feel quite familiar with.

Thanks for your ideas.