# How to combine multiple files in a single pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have 5 csv files in a folder: 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv, 4.csv, 5.csv. All files having the same structure and column names.

I would like all of the files to be in a single pandas dataframe, df. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading multiple csv files of a folder into one dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289386/loading-multiple-csv-files-of-a-folder-into-one-dataframe) or [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20906474/15497888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv')
df1.concat(df2)
# this will concat rows from df1 into df2
```

Answer (score 1):

`glob` can be a useful package for this, along with the `pandas.concat` method.

This approach creates a list of the `*.csv` files in a directory, reads each one to a DataFrame which is then appended to a list, and then the list is concatenated together into one DataFrame.

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for fin in glob.glob('*.csv'):
  dfs.append(pd.read_csv(fin))
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```